# Can I set types to the World context in cucumber?

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I am starting a new cucumber-selenium project in Typescript, and I would like to store Driver in the world context. The problem is that if I set it as in [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md), the `Driver` type is not accessible to step definitions.

Meaning that in my first step

```
Given('First step', async function () {
  this.driver.get('http://vacuumlabs.com')
})
```

the object `driver` has type `any`, because `this` is of type `World` and not `CustomWorld`. Is there a way I can change that?

I am using

```
    "@types/cucumber": "6.0.1",
    "cucumber": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
```

(because `@cucumber/cucumber` resolves `this` as `any`)

Answer (score 0):

### setting world type

Seems like this can be done in two ways...

```
Given('I am setting World type', async function (this: MyWorldType) {
  ...
})
```

or

```
Given<MyWorldType>('I am setting World type', async function () {
  ...
})
```

### defining world type

So it would be something like this...

```
import { World as CucumberWorld } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import { Driver } from 'selenium';
import { OtherCustomThing } from 'custom-things';

export interface MyWorldType extends CucumberWorld {
    driver: Driver;
    myOtherCustomAttribute: OtherCustomThing;
    ...
}
```